# AWS: Unable to connect to host error while sending email with corp account using AWS SES

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, email, jakarta-mail, amazon-ses

I am writing a program to send and access my org mailbox(outlook) using `Java Mail API` and [Amazon Simple Email Service](https://aws.amazon.com/ses/).

I followed [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/send-using-smtp-java.html) `smtp` example. Got the `ses` username and password created. But when I try the code example, it gives me error message saying

`Couldn't connect to host, port: email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com, 587; timeout -1`

I added my org domain(`myorg.com`) added for verification and also the sender id but nothing seems to working.

Is there anything else I need to do? Here is the code am using:

```
public class AWSEmailSender {


    static final String FROM = "myEmail@myorg.com";
    static final String FROMNAME = "Hello";


    static final String TO = "roger@myorg.com";

    // Replace smtp_username with your Amazon SES SMTP user name.
    static final String SMTP_USERNAME = "***************";

    // Replace smtp_password with your Amazon SES SMTP password.
    static final String SMTP_PASSWORD = "*****************************";

    // The name of the Configuration Set to use for this message.
    // If you comment out or remove this variable, you will also need to
    // comment out or remove the header below.
    static final String CONFIGSET = "ConfigSet";

    // Amazon SES SMTP host name. This example uses the US West (Oregon) region.
    // See http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/regions.html#region-endpoints
    // for more information.
    static final String HOST = "email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com";

    // The port you will connect to on the Amazon SES SMTP endpoint. 
    static final int PORT = 587;

    static final String SUBJECT = "Amazon SES test (SMTP interface accessed using Java)";

    static final String BODY = String.join(
            System.getProperty("line.separator"),
            "<h1>Amazon SES SMTP Email Test</h1>",
            "<p>This email was sent with Amazon SES using the ", 
            "<a href='https://github.com/javaee/javamail'>Javamail Package</a>",
            " for <a href='https://www.java.com'>Java</a>."
        );

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        // Create a Properties object to contain connection configuration information.
        Properties props = System.getProperties();
        props.put("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", PORT); 
        props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");

        // Create a Session object to represent a mail session with the specified properties. 
        Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props);

        // Create a message with the specified information. 
        MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(session);
        msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(FROM,FROMNAME));
        msg.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(TO));
        msg.setSubject(SUBJECT);
        msg.setContent(BODY,"text/html");

        // Add a configuration set header. Comment or delete the 
        // next line if you are not using a configuration set
        msg.setHeader("X-SES-CONFIGURATION-SET", CONFIGSET);

        // Create a transport.
        Transport transport = session.getTransport();

        // Send the message.
        try
        {
            System.out.println("Sending...");

            // Connect to Amazon SES using the SMTP username and password you specified above.
            transport.connect(HOST, SMTP_USERNAME, SMTP_PASSWORD);

            // Send the email.
            transport.sendMessage(msg, msg.getAllRecipients());
            System.out.println("Email sent!");
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("The email was not sent.");
            System.out.println("Error message: " + ex.getMessage());
        }
        finally
        {
            // Close and terminate the connection.
            transport.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: is this script running on ec2? Is the outbound port open? The timeout usually indicate it cannot reach it. What region are you running this?

Comment: Am not running it on ec2 rather locally over org network. Usually with simple `javamail api` setup, it works. I just have to change the host name to my org's host.
Though, final deployment would be over ec2 only.

Comment: Is your org behind a firewall?  Maybe you need to [connect through a proxy server](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#proxy)?